# Configure nginx proxy_pass alongside baseHref?

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm facing issues since i want to run an Angular 9 app on Kubernetes with i18n.

My app call an API with **/api/** who is proxied by nginx to another pod (rest-api).

Since i added i18n, i can get to work different version of my app on production. But can't find a way to make APIs call working ! In each version, my api call start with **/fr/api/some_request** or **/en/api/some_request** .. which is dynamicaly added by the baseHref

What is the nginx configuration to transform */en/api/* - */fr/api/* to /api/ ?

My structure is :

```
 - dist/ :
   - fr/
   - en/
```

I build the dist with :

- **FR :** `ng build --prod --i18n-locale fr --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.fr.xlf --output-path=dist/fr --base-href /fr/`
- **EN :** `ng build --prod --i18n-locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/translate/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist/en --base-href /en/`

This is my nginx conf :

```
server {
   ...
   location /fr/ { 
      autoindex on;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /fr/index.html;
   }

   location /en/ {
      autoindex on;
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /en/index.html;
   }

   # Default to FR
   location / {
      # Autoindex is disabled here + the $uri$args/ is missing from try_files
      try_files $uri$args /fr/index.html;
   }

   # Proxy to API call (old config working without i18n)
   location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000;
   }
}
```

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this location:

```
  location ~ .*/api/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1;
  }
```

This is a regex location that match any URI with /api/ anywhere in it. For example it will work on:

```
example.com/api/foo/bar
example.com/api/
example.com/something/api/foo/bar
```

There is a capture group (.*) to record whatever was after /api/. It is saved as a positional variable $1 (because it's the first and only capture group in the expression). Using it you can build an exact path to your API backend:

```
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/$1;
```

It will turn the examples above into:

```
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/foo/bar
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/
proxy_pass http://rest-api:9000/api/foo/bar
```